# Einstein notation difficulties

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, tensors

I'm just learning the Einstein index notation, and came across this derivation in a textbook. I couldn't follow the steps. Can someone please help me out?

The first order differential equation:

$$\bigg(- ik_i \frac{dM_i}{dt} - \frac{1}{2}k_i k_j \frac{dU_{ij}}{dt} - iY_{ij}k_iM_j - Y_{ij}k_iU_{jl}k_l + D_{ij}k_ik_j \bigg)P = 0$$

where non-indicial $i$ (prefix in first and third term in the brackets above) is $\sqrt{-1}$ and

$$P = \exp \bigg(-ik_iM_i(t) - \frac{1}{2}k_ik_jY_{ij}(t) \bigg)$$

implies that ($\bf{I \: don't \: understand \: this \: step}$)

$$\frac{dU_{ij}}{dt} = - Y_{il}U_{lj} - Y_{jl}U_{li} + 2D_{ij}$$

given that $U_{ij} = U_{ji}$

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can get the proper font for $\exp$ using `\exp`. For other operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`. Further formatting advice [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: Thank you for the formatting tips! I'm quite new here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(- ik_i \frac{dM_i}{dt} - \frac{1}{2}k_i k_j \frac{dU_{ij}}{dt} - iY_{ij}k_iM_j - Y_{ij}k_iU_{jl}k_l + D_{ij}k_ik_j)P = 0$$

We know $P \ne 0$, real and imagine equal zero separately.

$$- \frac{1}{2}k_i k_j \frac{dU_{ij}}{dt} - Y_{ij}k_iU_{jl}k_l + D_{ij}k_ik_j = 0 ~~~~~~~(1)$$

$$- k_i \frac{dM_i}{dt}  - Y_{ij}k_iM_j  = 0~~~~~~~~(2)$$

for (1), 
$$- \frac{1}{2}k_i k_j \frac{dU_{ij}}{dt} - Y_{ij}k_iU_{jl}k_l + D_{ij}k_ik_j = 0 $$

$$ k_i k_j \frac{dU_{ij}}{dt}= - 2Y_{ij}k_iU_{jl}k_l + 2D_{ij}k_ik_j  $$
$$ k_i k_j \frac{dU_{ij}}{dt} =- Y_{ij}k_iU_{jl}k_l- Y_{ij}k_iU_{lj}k_l + 2D_{ij}k_ik_j  $$

then you need to exchange j, l so you can remove $k_ik_j$
$$ k_i k_j \frac{dU_{ij}}{dt} =- Y_{il}k_iU_{lj}k_j- Y_{il}k_iU_{jl}k_j + 2D_{ij}k_ik_j  $$

$$ \frac{dU_{ij}}{dt} =- Y_{il}U_{lj}- Y_{il}U_{jl} + 2D_{ij}  $$

Comment: In dropping $k_ik_j$, you assumed universal quantification over $k$ that hadn't been specified.

Comment: That's true. I made an assumption here.